# Need google analytics for each search result

Tags: php, mysql, record

I have a mySQL database with several records.  Each record will appear as a profile page when the client performs a search and finds.

I need to keep track of each record to know the traffic for each record - how many times this particular record has been viewed, etc..

How do I incorporate Google Analytics with each individual record.  Do I insert google code for each record?

Appreciate any feedback.

Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Content/Pages and segment the pages using the advance search.

If I am guessing correctly you should be using query strings for each profile.

Place the profile ID in the search. Example ?id=499

You can download the content with the Google Analytics API.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/

Answer (score 1):

You probably will want to use [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) to track this.